# UiApp Merge 2 Cells in a Grid

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script **UiApp**, is there any way to merge 2 adjacent cells in a `Grid`?

*Quick link to [`Grid` doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/grid)*

Looking through it, I see nothing about merge capability. Take the following example:

[image]

What I want to do is merge the cells @ `[0,5]` and @ `[1,5]` So that the `TextArea` for `Description` is a bit better-centered.

Is there any possible way to do this at the current time? I don't want to have to revert to using [`Flex Table`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/flex-table) for this... is that my only option? Are there any other workarounds like embedding the encircled elements in another panel or something similar?

**Solution**: CSS margin properties on the `Grid` or `Widgets` (through `setStyleAttributes()`). Apparently this is the behavior of `Widgets` in a `Grid`: CSS styles *almost* bypass `Grid` constraints; i.e., if you set a bizarre `bottomMargin` on a Widget, it can *almost* move out of the `Grid`, which acts as a "centering" between two cells. So I just did the following:

`textArea.setStyleAttribute("marginBottom", "-75px");` which gave the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using 2 grids, one with the textArea (and the 5 widgets of the first row)  and the other with the other elements...
This latter should have a negative top margin to allow you to get the right vertical distribution on the 5 first left widgets.
I didn't try the negative margin but it should work.

Let me know if you try it :-)

Comment: I did manage to get that to work - the negative top margin on the second Grid definitely put them close together. It's good for the moment, this is just the first version of this project - I'll probably convert most of it to FlexTables later for flexibility, but the documentation on that is confusing (in my opinion) and my first couple of tries I failed to get it to work. I have experience with Grids though ;) Thanks!

Comment: Chouette :-)  hmmmm I mean: Nice, glad it brought a working solution, and ...thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are so many CSS style attributes to choose from, and I've never really worked with CSS nor HTML (aside from basic things). It turns out that every Widget can be '*manipulated*' through '*barriers*' of the `Grid` by using *margin* properties. Interestingly enough, setting a large `topMargin` or `bottomMargin` (whichever direction one would want) basically acts as a "cell merge", which is close enough to what I wanted! Very good suggestion, I'll be using this to more closely align the rest of my seemingly-randomly placed Widgets ;)